# Why does chrome errors with NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID on admin.localhost with SAN and CN set to *.localhost

Tags: certificate

I want to create a http/2 server with admin panel attached as subdomain.

I created certificate with CN=*.localhost and subjectAltName = *.localhost and localhost

```
# server.scr.cnf
[req]
default_bits = 2048
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
distinguished_name = dn

[dn]
CN = *.localhost
OU=Random
C=US
ST=RandomState
L=RandomCity
O=RandomOrganization
emailAddress=hello@example.com
```

```
# v3.ext
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = *.localhost
DNS.2 = localhost
```

Then i went to chrome (tested on stable (88.0.4324.146) & canary (90.0.4410.2) versions, no differences) and saw these results:

1. https://localhost:7000 works properly, no errors.
2. https://admin.localhost:7000 doesn't work, but i excepted that certificate won't give any errors (no errors on server side, proceeding to admin.localhost:7000 gives appropriate page) -
   [image: The certificate and the error]

I've tried to change CN to localhost, tried to add more wildcards such as *.*.localhost, (and etc.), nothing of these worked.
The only way to fix the problem i see is to add admin.localhost to alt_names, but it's a burden for me, because of need to add each sub to alt_names, so i don't appreciate that solution and i want to understand why didn't the *.localhost work.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68514822/1240492