# What is the correct way to generate a selfsigned cert for *.localhost ('wildcard')

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https, openssl

I can't for the life of me get chrome to work with a wildcard cert ("*.localhost")

Here is what I'm doing to generate said cert.

First I gen my ca

```
openssl genrsa -out priv/cert/ca.key 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -subj "/C=US/O=_Development \
CA/CN=Development certificates" -key priv/cert/ca.key -sha256 \
-days 3650 -out priv/cert/ca.crt
```

Then I gen my localhost

```
openssl genrsa -out priv/cert/localhost.key 2048
openssl req -new -subj "/C=US/O=Local Development/CN=*.localhost" -key \
priv/cert/localhost.key -out priv/cert/localhost.csr
```

Then I make my ext file

```
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth, clientAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[req]
req_extensions = req_ext
[req_distinguished_name]
commonName_default = localhost
[req_ext]
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = *.localhost
DNS.2 = foo.localhost
DNS.3 = localhost
```

Then I sign.

```
openssl x509 -req \
    -in priv/cert/localhost.csr \
    -extfile priv/cert/localhost.ext \
    -CA priv/cert/ca.crt \
    -CAkey priv/cert/ca.key \
    -CAcreateserial \
    -out priv/cert/localhost.crt \
    -days 365 \
    -sha256
```

After trusting my crt and navigate locally to say localhost or foo.localhost I get all green but if I go to say bar.localhost the wild card does not work and I get a NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID on chrome.

what am I missing here. I've addressed the Subject Alternative Name, I've ruled out that SAN via foo works. Common name does not even matter anymore from what I read. I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR: Browsers will not accept `*.localhost` in a certificate.

In `*.localhost` the `localhost` suffix is treated as a top level domain (TLD) and wildcards directly below a TLD are not allowed. The idea behind this is basically that no single organization actually owns a TLD like `com` and thus allowing a certificate for `*.com` would be pretty dangerous. Therefore `*.localhost` will not be accepted, while `*.foo.localhost` will.

For more on this see [Wildcard *.localhost SSL with Nginx and Chrome](https://serverfault.com/questions/811111/wildcard-localhost-ssl-with-nginx-and-chrome) and [Can a wildcard SSL certificate be issued for a second level domain?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6873/can-a-wildcard-ssl-certificate-be-issued-for-a-second-level-domain).